# 3 value quadratic simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $a,b,$ and $c$ are real numbers and

- $a^2+2b=7$
- $b^2+4c=-7$
- $c^2+6a=-14$

Find $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

This question was given to secondary school students in a team of 4 with 3 other questions to complete with 6 minutes. I believe there is a better method than just substituting and solving as that would go over the time constraints. Is there a better method or are you just supposed to be fast?

The answer given is $14$ if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to recognise that $14=1^2+2^2+3^2$, the squares of halved coefficients in the equations. Thus, summing all three equations:
$$
a^2+2b+b^2+4c+c^2+6a = -14,\\
(a^2+6a+9)+(b^2+2b+1)+(c^2+4c+4) = 0,\\
(a+3)^2+(b+1)^2+(c+2)^2 = 0.
$$

The sum of squares is zero only if every square is zero, thus $a=-3$, $b=-1$, $c=-2$ and we already know what the sum of squares of these numbers are.